# Error parsing XML on Fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple `RSS` reader with `NavigationDrawer`. I've done a `Parser` class using `RssParserSax` and a `RSS` handler. My app crash when I execute the `AsynTask`. My logcat:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
            at me.apps.rss.News$LoadXMLTask.onPostExecute(CNews.java:53)
            at me.apps.rss.News$LoadXMLTask.onPostExecute(CNews.java:45)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And my View code. Note that the task only executes when I press the button.

```
public class News extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private List<whatsnew> news;
    private TextView txtresult;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_news, container, false);
        Button but = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.but);

        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LoadXMLTask task1 = new LoadXMLTask();
                task1.execute("http://www.feedforall.com/sample-feed.xml");
            }
        });



        return v;
    }

    private class LoadXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
        protected Boolean doInBackground (String ... params){
            RssParserSax saxparser= new RssParserSax(params[0]);
            news = saxparser.parse();
            return true;
        }

        protected  void onPostExecute (Boolean result){
            txtresult.setText("");
            for(int i=0; i<news.size(); i++)
            {
               //nothing
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
txtresult.setText("");
```

This is the problem, reference is probably `null`.

Actually, this 2 lines in your stack trace tell you exactly what the problem is:

```
at me.apps.rss.News$LoadXMLTask.onPostExecute(CNews.java:53)
at me.apps.rss.News$LoadXMLTask.onPostExecute(CNews.java:45)
```

Lines 45, 53 in CNews.java are the places where Exception is thrown. If you look at this lines you'll know which reference is `null`.

So the solution is to add inside `onCreateView`:

```
 txtresult = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.your_id);
```

Comment: Welcome, I hope next time you'll be able to spot error quickly. Reading stack trace is a way to go.

Comment: Another thing is how to put the same element in a ListView, because I'm trying and I simply cant...the arrayadapter constructor don't let me use the data from the parser.

Answer (score 1):

At the `onCreateView` you forgot to initialize `txtresult` field, that is why `txtresult.setText("");` gives you a `NPE`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to uninitialized `txtResult` this operation  `for(int i=0; i<news.size(); i++)` is also unsafe because `news` is not initialized either. I think a better way to utilize your AsyncTask is:

```
    protected Boolean doInBackground (String ... params){
        RssParserSax saxparser= new RssParserSax(params[0]);
        news = saxparser.parse(); //assuming this doesn't throw exception
        if (news != null){
         return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected  void onPostExecute (Boolean result){

        if (result){
            for (int i =0; i<news.size();i++){...}
            txtresult.setText("success");
        }else{
            txtresult.setText("failed");
        }

    }
```